# Unzipping files in REACT and then rezipping it again

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an application which is a REACT frontend and a python flask backend.
The logic is as follows.

- End user uploads a zip file
- Sample zip file structure

```
source.zip
 dontextract             
 extractfile1            
 extractfile2
```

I want to extract extractfile1 and extractfile2 from the zip file and then create a new zip with these two extracted files. Once that is done, I need to send this new zip file to a backend service.

I am finding various solutions on the internet through node packages such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/unzip and https://www.npmjs.com/package/unzipper but these are also suggesting unzipping files in the backend, is there a way to perform this task in the front-end on the REACT side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [JSZIP](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/)

Example:

```
const zip = new JSZip();
zip.loadAsync(<YOUR .ZIP FILE>).then(<YOUR FILES IN AN ARRAY>)
```

Comment: you mean in a REACT app?

Comment: Yes, but react or angular or ember or whatever the application type does not matter.

Answer (score -1):

My answer is no. You should handle everything related to file (read/write) in server side, not from browser. Like your above two packages, it's used for NodeJS. Not only the problem with browser API to read/write files, it's also the security risk when you let the hacker use Javascript to modify file and send to the server.

Comment: I am of the same understanding but trying to double check that I am not missing anything. the zip file I get from the user is about 150-200MB in size and I need to upload the whole file to only use two files which are generally a few KB in size, so trying to figure out a way to upload only the relevant files

Comment: You can manage zip files in frontend without any problem. both zip and unzip

Comment: Thanks @F.bernal for your solution. But 200MB zip file is a different problem. You need to consider between security risk and user experience. Why don't let user upload needed files instead?

Comment: But that is another topic. the question is manage zip files in frontend side and yes, it can be done. Another thing is the nature of the application if it has sense or not.

Comment: You can just use SHA256-SUM or something like that to check if something is missing or not @VikG